# How to render a translation similar to this phrase in the Odyssey

Tags: homer, ancient-greek

It says in the Book 6, line 160, of the Odyssey: "**οὔτ᾽ ἄνδρ᾽ οὔτε γυναῖκα: σέβας μ᾽ ἔχει εἰσορόωντα.**" But if I wanted to change roughly to: **I have never laid eyes on anyone** *but* **you.**  How exactly would I've to do it? I know it wouldn't be as simple as adding: **δέ / δ᾽** (And full disclosure that I've tried -(much to the displeasure of my teacher)- but in my defense it has only been weeks that I've been trying to learn another language. The first being always the hardest. And Greek been maybe an odd choice for to be that, given the level of difficulty. Also, I couldn't find prepositions (equivalent) to: **like, or such as**). Well, anyway, could anyone assist me on phrasing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line being translated here is actually the preceding line, *Odyssey* 6.159:

> οὐ γάρ πω τοιοῦτον ἴδον βροτὸν ὀφθαλμοῖσιν

Literally, this means "for not yet have I seen such a mortal with (my) eyes". The words "like you" are not in the Greek, though they're implied. This means there isn't a simple change you could make that would turn the meaning from "like you" into "but you".

Still, if you want to say "anyone but you", you need a Greek word meaning "but" in the sense of "except". δέ, ἀλλά and other such words won't work because they mean "but" in the sense of "however". Instead, you could use the preposition πλήν "except", which takes the genitive, so πλὴν σοῦ "except you". Or you could use εἰ μή "if not", which is idiomatically often used to mean "except"; in this case it would be εἰ μὴ σέ, with the accusative because "you" acts as the direct object of "seen".

It's hard to fit either of these into a Homeric hexameter line. The following is a bit strained in terms of word order, but at least it scans:

> οὐ γάρ πω ἴδον εἰ μὴ σὲ βροτὸν ὀφθαλμοῖσιν

Fitting in πλὴν σοῦ can be done with some more changes:

> οὐ γὰρ πλὴν σοῦ ὄπωπά τινα βροτὸν ὀφθαλμοῖσιν

Comment: Thank you so much. My bad on the wrong line and I should've mentioned my unconcern in fitting a hexameter.Thanks again!